# Linux Environment Variable and C project getenv()

Tags: c, linux, path, environment-variables, getenv

I need to use an environment variable for a C project so i did this in a terminal:

```
export FILE_CONFIG="/home/pc/file.conf"
```

***file.conf*** is a file which i created.

If I do `env` in the terminal, I can see "FILE_CONFIG" in the list with its value (/home/pc/file.conf).
I want to assign to **path_to_config** -> /home/pc/file.conf
SO in a **.C** program i did this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* path_to_config = getenv("FILE_CONFIG");
```

But the `getenv` doesn't returns the path to FILE_CONFIG..
When I look in Debug mode path_to_config value is 0x0.
I've tried with other environment variables but I could not do with this one in particular which I exported.

Comment: Just to test, do a `system("env")` just before your `getenv`.

Comment: Just to make sure: the shell in which you set the variable has to be the same that you call your binary from. Is that the case?

Comment: well, it prints a list, but I cant see my enviroment variable

Comment: Marcus Rickert, I dont know if set the variable in the same shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess: you are running your program from the IDE. The environment an IDE provides to your program is totally unrelated to the environment where you export your variable. Suggestion: run your program from the command line *at the terminal* in which you did `export`. You shall see your variable all right.

Then search your IDE for a way to specify an environment for a target program, and set it there.

Optionally, add the export line to your shell's startup script.

Comment: yeah! is Eclipse. I can specify an environment for a target program but only in Debug mode can see thr results..